# Stubbing Chained Methods with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

I want to call a named_scope that will only return one record, but the named_scope returns an array, that's not a big deal as I can just chain it with .first:

```
Model.named_scope(param).first
```

and this works, what I am struggling with is how to stub the chained call. Does anyone have a reference or an answer on how I would go about achieving this with Rspec mocking?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured something out.

```
Client.stub!(:named_scope).and_return(@clients = mock([Client]))
@clients.stub!(:first).and_return(@client = mock(Client))
```

which allows me to call my controller:

```
@client = Client.named_scope(param).first
```

It works, but is there a better solution?

EDIT:

The release of rspec 1.2.6 allows us to use stub_chain meaning it can now be:

```
Client.stub_chain(:named_scope, :chained_call).and_return(@clients = [mock(Client)])
```

This was top of my head, as always check the api for specifics :)

Comment: Maybe move the EDIT: section to the top of the answer

Answer (score 2):

Better version of

```
Client.stub!(:named_scope).and_return(@clients = mock([Client]))
@clients.stub!(:first).and_return(@client = mock(Client))
```

will be:

```
Client.should_receive(:named_scope).with(param).and_return do
  record = mock_model(Comm)
  record.should_receive(:do_something_else)
  [record]  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite old and hence there are few enhancements in how stubbing can be done. Now you can use stub_chain method to stub a chain of method calls.
For example:

`@client = Client.named_scope(param).first`

can be stubbed with:

`Client.stub_chain(:named_scope,:first).and_return(@client = mock(Client))`

More examples of stub_chaining:

```
describe "stubbing a chain of methods" do
  subject { Object.new }

  context "given symbols representing methods" do
    it "returns the correct value" do
      subject.stub_chain(:one, :two, :three).and_return(:four)
      subject.one.two.three.should eq(:four)
    end
  end

  context "given a string of methods separated by dots" do
    it "returns the correct value" do
      subject.stub_chain("one.two.three").and_return(:four)
      subject.one.two.three.should eq(:four)
    end
  end
end
```

[or please have a look at:](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods#stub-a-chain-of-methods)

Long live the rspecs!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is in a controller spec?

Your own suggestion should work fine. Another possibility is to move the named_scope call inside your model, to avoid the issue entirely. This would also be in line with the "fat models, thin controllers" advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already done the thin controller thing by putting the query into a named scope where it can be reused. Here is some code I used before I started using named scopes.

```
  def mock_comm(stubs={})
    @mock_comm ||= mock_model(Comm, stubs)
  end

  describe "responding to GET index" do

    it "should expose all comms as @comms" do
      Comm.should_receive(:find).with(:all).and_return([mock_comm])
      get :index
      assigns[:comms].should == [mock_comm]
    end
# ...
```

I would probably write code quite similar to what you have already, but maybe put it in a helper that allows me to reuse it. The other thing is to use a different mocking framework that maybe gives you more control. Have a look at Ryan Bates' railscast on RSpec - it's a bit old now but still some good ideas in there.