# What's the best way to test delayed_job chains with rSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, delayed-job

Currently when I have a delayed method in my code like the following:

```
CommentMailer.delay.deliver_comments(@comment, true)
```

I write something like this in my spec:

```
dj = mock("DelayProxy")
CommentMailer.should_receive(:delay).and_return(dj)
dj.should_receive(:deliver_comments).with(comment, true)
```

Is there a better way to handle this and/or chained methods like that in rSpec in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some discussions about chaining methods in rSpec that I found helpful:

[Stubbing Chained Methods with Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664755/stubbing-chained-methods-with-rspec)

http://groups.google.com/group/rspec/browse_thread/thread/6b8394836d2390b0#

Answer (score 28):

We can just have one more line in the **before** block as following:

```
CommentMailer.stub(:delay).and_return(CommentMailer)
```

Then you then can have the normal mock check as following:

```
CommentMailer.should_receive(:deliver_comments).with(comment, true)
```

Comment: Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated in rspec-3.  This seems to work `expect(CommentMailer).to receive(:delay).and_return(CommentMailer)`.  If you dont want to explicitly test it, you could use `allow` instead of `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

```
describe '#perform' do
    subject do
      Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
      proc { worker.perform() }
    end

    it { is_expected.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.length }.by(2) }
  end
```

Set delayed job as false and u can test it like simple