# Rspec testing delayed_job

Tags: rspec, delayed-job

I have some complex, long-running delayed_job processes in my application. I am using Rspec to test individual methods and classes used in the processes, but I would also like to perform many of end-to-end background jobs, with different test data.

I couldn't find anything on the delayed_job wiki on this, and this SO question looks interesting but I didn't really understand what is happening here.
[What's the best way to test delayed_job chains with rSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030974/whats-the-best-way-to-test-delayed-job-chains-with-rspec)

I can easily set up the test data with a factory, and then call the class that starts the background processing. I expect the tests to take a long time to complete.

edited background code

```
class Singleplex
    def perform(batch_id,user)   
      batch = start_batch(batch_id,user)
        ... do lots of stuff ...
    end
    handle_asynchronously :perform, queue: :singleplex, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.second.from_now }
```

**spec/factories/batches.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :batch do
    batch_type 'singleplex'
    name 'valid panel'
    status 'ready'
  end

  factory :batch_detail do
    chrom 7
    chrom_start 140435012
    chrom_end 140435012
    target_offset 150
    padding 4
    primer3_parameter_id 1
    snp_mask 't'
    status 'ready'
    batch
  end
end
```

Then run the test like this

```
describe Batch do  
  it 'runs Singleplex for a valid panel' do
    batch = FactoryGirl.create(:batch)
    user = User.find(1)
    status =  Singleplex.new.perform(batch.id,user)
    expect(status.should == true)
  end
end
```

I have two problems to solve:

1) How to tell the test to wait until the delayed_job call is completed before validating the results ?

2) To validate the results I will need to check values in multiple tables. What is the best way to do this in Rspec?

EDIT

I should add I get a delayed_job object, so of course the status check fails. The jobs take at least 10 minutes usually.

```
1) Batch runs Singleplex for a valid panel
     Failure/Error: expect(status.should == true)
       expected: true
            got: #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: nil, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject:...", last_error: nil, run_at: nil, locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, queue: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> (using ==)
```

Comment: By the way, it looks like you're mixing RSpec's `should` and `expect` syntax. `expect(status.should == true)` should be either `status.should == true` or `expect(status).to == true`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about doing this. All of them require that you execute the job in your code.

Method 1: A test which queues the job and then tells the `DelayedJob::Worker` to complete it.

```
describe Batch do  
  it 'runs Singleplex for a valid panel' do
    batch = FactoryGirl.create(:batch)
    user = User.find(1)
    Singleplex.new.perform(batch.id,user)
    expect(Delayed::Worker.new.work_off).to eq [1, 0] # Returns [successes, failures]
    # Add expectations which check multiple tables to make sure the work is done
  end
end
```

Method 2: A test which runs the job in question with queueing disabled, and checks for the desired results. You can delay queuing by calling `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false` somewhere in your testing configuration or in a `before` block.

```
before(:each) do
  Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
end
describe Batch do  
  it 'runs Singleplex for a valid panel' do
    batch = FactoryGirl.create(:batch)
    user = User.find(1)
    Singleplex.new.perform(batch.id,user)
    # expectations which check that the work is done
  end
end
```

This method has, however, been known to [cause issues with callbacks](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/08/16/testing-with-delayed-jobs/).

Method 3: Write an observer that watches for any new jobs that are created and runs them. This way you won't have to manually declare "work_off" in your tests. Artsy has a [gist for this](https://gist.github.com/dblock/3370052).

It's also a good idea to have tests elsewhere that make sure jobs get queued as expected

```
it "queues welcome when a user is created" do
  expect(Delayed::Job.count).to eq 0
  # Create user step
  expect(Delayed::Job.count).to eq 1 # You should really be looking for the count of a specific job.
end
```

Comment: Thanks @faraz, for method 3, where did you add the references to `delayed_job_observer.rb`, is it in `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: Use `rails_helper.rb` if you're using the newer organization format, otherwise `spec_helper.rb` works.

Comment: in your first method, shouldn't the job be performed right away, it won't queue it right?

Comment: @jshah The job will not be performed right away since there's no background worker running to consume the job during tests unless, for whatever crazy reason, you decided that running a background worker is a good idea.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to run delayed job around single test or a set of tests, you can add this to your spec_helper.rb

```
config.around(:each, :run_delayed_jobs) do |example|
  Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false

  example.run

  Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = true
end
```

And call it with:

```
it 'runs the job', :run_delayed_jobs do
  # delayed job magic
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think anyone who use delayed job will face with this issue. In my case, I send email notifications in an asynchronous mode by using delayed job. When doing unit test, I usually need to verify if the mailer enqueue work has been done or not. In order to handle this, I write a custom matcher for Rspec like below:

```
  RSpec::Matchers.define :have_created_delayed_job do |method_name|
    match do |_|
      Delayed::Job.all.find do |job|
        # rubocop:disable Security/YAMLLoad
        YAML.load(job.handler).method_name == method_name
        # rubocop:enable Security/YAMLLoad
      end
    end
    failure_message do |subject|
      "Expected that #{subject} would have created a delayed job with method name #{method_name}.\n
      But we didn't find the matching job."
    end
  end
```

Then in your testing code, you can do it like this:

```
expect(subject).to have_created_delayed_job(:your_method_name)
```